# How do I find the middle word of a sentence written in an excel cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

I have a 3 word sentence in a cell. All words are separated by ":". I can find and extract the left value and right values, but not the middle word.
How can I get the middle word?

[image]

Comment: show us how you find the right and left, you may be able to expand on this to do mid

Comment: What about something like `=MID(C3, SEARCH(":",C3) + 1, SEARCH(":",C3,SEARCH(":",C3)+1) - SEARCH(":",C3) - 1)` (Untested)

Comment: use =replace() to delete the first and last part, you should be left with the middle

Comment: Thank you for support .It was really helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (This should be more in line with your original ones):

```
=IFERROR(TRIM(MID(C3, FIND(":",C3) + 1, FIND(":",C3,FIND(":",C3)+1) - FIND(":",C3) - 1)),"")
```

Ways to find the first and last word:

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(C3, FIND("-",C3,1)-1),"")

=IFERROR(TRIM(RIGHT(C3,LEN(C3) - FIND("-", C3, FIND("-", C3) + 1))),"")
```

`TRIM()` is used to remove space, which might be something you desire.

`IFERROR()` is just used to replace the `IF(ISERR())` to make the function a bit shorter and easier to read.

Comment: Thank you for support .It was really helpful

Answer (score 0):

For example your text located at cell C3.

Here is the formula:

```
=MID(C3, (FIND(":",C3)+1), ((FIND(":", C3, (FIND(":",C3)+1)))-(FIND(":",C3)+1)))
```

Explanation:

1. Find location (number of character) of first `:`, and add 1.
2. By knowing location (number of character) of first `:` [step 1], find the location (number of character) of second `:`.
3. By using function =MID(), get the text.

   =MID(text_location, [STEP 1] + 1, [STEP 2] - [STEP 1])

Hope it is useful.

Comment: Thanks for posting the step-by-step explanation, but your answer is the same as [Christofer Weber’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/1415606/150988#1415641) except for the extra parentheses and the fact that you ***left out*** the error handling.  I’m not accusing you of copying, but please, when you’re getting ready to post an answer, check whether you are adding new information or just duplicating.